# Can I stop a click from triggering website's usual actions?

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-chrome-extension, reactjs, content-script

As an experiment with React.js, I am trying to build a chrome extension that uses a content script to inject a input field (and now a button too) into certain websites. In this case I am trying to inject it into Twitter. It looks like this:
[image]
*please note that the code puts the button and input below the text, but it will have the same result*

The injection works, but I can't actually use the input. I inject the element into tweets on the home page, and when I click on the input to type in it, it triggers the tweet and expands or contracts. This removes the focus from the input rendering it useless. I have tried to call back focus `onBlur`, and `stopPropagation()` `onClick`, but `onClick` isn't triggered and I'm not sure how to bring back focus with `onBlur`. How can I stop losing focus?

If you want to test it yourself, react-with-addons.js came from the starter kit [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

**EDIT:** I tried adding  button to the code to see if I could click on that, and I can. I can click on it with out triggering the tweet itself. This means there is something specific to the input box that is causing trouble, or there is something in the button that is blocking propagation of the click. 
Is there something special triggered when you click on an input field that other elements don't have that the tweets might have?

**EDIT 2:** I have now tried to add stopPropagation to a containing div and increasing it's z-index, neither of them will stop it.

**EDIT 3:** I have now tried onMouseDown(and onMouseUp, and onClick, all at the same time) with stopPropagation, with no luck. The strange part is I tried isPropagationStopped() afterwards, and it returns true. If this is so then why is Twitter still being triggered?

**test_input.js**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var Test_Input = React.createClass({
    maintain_focus: function(){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("=====");
    },
    refocus: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    handle_click: function{
        console.log("clicked");
    }
    render: function(){
        return (<div>
                       <button onclick={this.handle_click}>
                       <input className="new_note_input" placeholder="Note" onclick={this.maintain_focus} onBlur={this.refocus}></input>
                   </div>);
    }
});
var elements_to_append_to = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
[].forEach.call(elements_to_append_to, function(element){
    var container = $("<span />");
    $(element).after(container);
    React.renderComponent(<Test_Input />, container[0]);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Input",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["tabs", "bookmarks", "declarativeWebRequest", "*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://twitter.com/*"],
            "css":["src/social_notes.css"],
            "js":[ "build/jquery-2.1.0.min.js", "build/react-with-addons.js", "build/test_input.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where do you inject the input field on the Twitter home page. Could you show us? (maybe snapshot and HTML)

Comment: @Chickenrice added a screenshot, and since this is a content script there is no html, the chrome extension is able to be injected directly into a website.

Comment: Have you tried stopping propagation of the `focus` event of the input?

Comment: @ssorallen Yeah I tried that, no good.

Comment: is test_input.js really javascript?

Comment: maybe try to ensure that the event is being fired in the capturing phase, because if for some reason the twitter developers decided to add the listeners of the tweets in the capturing phase, they would fire before your handlers, but if you add it during the capturing phase as well it's pretty much guaranteed to be fired first

Comment: I have ran into some scenarios with React where stopPropagation did not do the job  for me. So I got hold of the native event object and did e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation().

Comment: @Markasoftware how do I specify what phase my handlers will fire off in?

Comment: @OnurYıldırım technically it's JSX. It's part of React.JS, you can see how it works here http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html. It's actually pretty cool.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled looks cool but I like to keep my syntax "Crackford" clean.

Comment: @nimgrg just tried your solution, and unfortunately it didn't work. I'm thinking that twitter may not be reacting to the usual events.

Comment: React implements synthetic event's and all events are delegated to window.document, my guess is you are seeing the problem because of this. Plus I injected a normal input element into a tweet and did an stopImmediatePropagtion and it seems to be not expanding the tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) works on event handlers. Since input field click triggers default behaviour, instead of `e.stopPropagation()`, `e.preventDefault()` with a `return false;` in the input box click handler should do the trick.

In the handler, do a `$(this).focus();` before returning false. This will keep the text box in focus.

eg:

```
$(".inputField").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).focus();
  return false;
})
```

Comment: You're solution worked, though it broke out of the React syntax. Any chance you know how to write it to work with in a React component?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click handler on the `div` you're inserting and do `e.stopPropagation()` in the handler, like this:

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var Test_Input = React.createClass({
    maintain_focus: function(){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("=====");
    },
    refocus: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    handle_click: function(){
        console.log("clicked");
    },
    div_click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    render: function(){
        return (<div onclick={this.div_click}>
                       <button onclick={this.handle_click}>
                       <input className="new_note_input" placeholder="Note" onclick={this.maintain_focus} onBlur={this.refocus}></input>
                   </div>);
    }
});
var elements_to_append_to = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
[].forEach.call(elements_to_append_to, function(element){
    var container = $("<span />");
    $(element).after(container);
    React.renderComponent(<Test_Input />, container[0]);
});
```

BTW, there are some syntax errors in your code.